# Is there a way to make talk back focus back to the previous view when a popup window closed in Android Studio?

Tags: java, android-studio, talkback

For example, I am running an app with **TalkBack** on, when I click on **button A**, the **TalkBack** will focus on **button A**, and it will launch a popup window, after I close the popup window, **TalkBack** will reset the focus to the **first view**, but how do I make it focus back to **button A** after I close popup window?